# Eclim commands in gvim close gvim, but The same commands work with vim in a terminal

Tags: vim, terminal, eclim

My problem is exactly as it sounds. For instance, if I type "PingEclim", gvim closes. On the other hand, the same commands work fine in a terminal. Why is this? GVim-7.4 Eclim-2.4.0

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Sadly, no man. Instead, I am using Eclipse with the Vrapper plugin and I am satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is long overdue, but the most likely culprit is your python setup. I was facing the same, and I found out that it wasn't just PingEclim that caused VIM to close, but any command that needed to run python. I was using portable python on windows and everything worked after I installed python normally.

Note: VIM might be telling you that it has python support when you run :echo has("python") yet still crash when you try to run a python command, so it's important to really test if you can run python commands.